# ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.....tensorflow==2.2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/shamangary/FSA-Net/blob/master/demo/demo_FSANET_ssd.py) code (this is the entire code that I've tried.):

```
import os
import cv2
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import numpy as np
from math import cos, sin
# from moviepy.editor import *
from lib.FSANET_model import *
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Average   

def draw_axis(img, yaw, pitch, roll, tdx=None, tdy=None, size = 50):
    print(yaw,roll,pitch)
    pitch = pitch * np.pi / 180
    yaw = -(yaw * np.pi / 180)
    roll = roll * np.pi / 180

    if tdx != None and tdy != None:
        tdx = tdx
        tdy = tdy
    else:
        height, width = img.shape[:2]
        tdx = width / 2
        tdy = height / 2

    # X-Axis pointing to right. drawn in red
    x1 = size * (cos(yaw) * cos(roll)) + tdx
    y1 = size * (cos(pitch) * sin(roll) + cos(roll) * sin(pitch) * sin(yaw)) + tdy

    # Y-Axis | drawn in green
    #        v
    x2 = size * (-cos(yaw) * sin(roll)) + tdx
    y2 = size * (cos(pitch) * cos(roll) - sin(pitch) * sin(yaw) * sin(roll)) + tdy

    # Z-Axis (out of the screen) drawn in blue
    x3 = size * (sin(yaw)) + tdx
    y3 = size * (-cos(yaw) * sin(pitch)) + tdy


    return img
    
def draw_results_ssd(detected,input_img,faces,ad,img_size,img_w,img_h,model,time_detection,time_network,time_plot):
    
   
    if detected.shape[2]>0:
        for i in range(0, detected.shape[2]):               
            confidence = detected[0, 0, i, 2]

            
            if confidence > 0.5:                 
                (h0, w0) = input_img.shape[:2]
                box = detected[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w0, h0, w0, h0])
                (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
               
                x1 = startX
                y1 = startY
                w = endX - startX
                h = endY - startY
                
                x2 = x1+w
                y2 = y1+h

                xw1 = max(int(x1 - ad * w), 0)
                yw1 = max(int(y1 - ad * h), 0)
                xw2 = min(int(x2 + ad * w), img_w - 1)
                yw2 = min(int(y2 + ad * h), img_h - 1)
                
                faces[i,:,:,:] = cv2.resize(input_img[yw1:yw2 + 1, xw1:xw2 + 1, :], (img_size, img_size))
                faces[i,:,:,:] = cv2.normalize(faces[i,:,:,:], None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)        
                
                face = np.expand_dims(faces[i,:,:,:], axis=0)
                p_result = model.predict(face)
                
                face = face.squeeze()
                img = draw_axis(input_img[yw1:yw2 + 1, xw1:xw2 + 1, :], p_result[0][0], p_result[0][1], p_result[0][2])
                
                input_img[yw1:yw2 + 1, xw1:xw2 + 1, :] = img
                
    cv2.imshow("result", input_img)
    
    return input_img 

def main():
    try:
        os.mkdir('./img')
    except OSError:
        pass    
   
    img_size = 64
    stage_num = [3,3,3]
    lambda_local = 1
    lambda_d = 1
    img_idx = 0
    detected = '' 
    time_network = 0
    time_plot = 0
    skip_frame = 1 
    ad = 0.6

    #Parameters
    num_capsule = 3
    dim_capsule = 16
    routings = 2
    stage_num = [3,3,3]
    lambda_d = 1
    num_classes = 3
    image_size = 64
    num_primcaps = 7*3
    m_dim = 5
    S_set = [num_capsule, dim_capsule, routings, num_primcaps, m_dim]

    model1 = FSA_net_Capsule(image_size, num_classes, stage_num, lambda_d, S_set)()
    model2 = FSA_net_Var_Capsule(image_size, num_classes, stage_num, lambda_d, S_set)()
    
    num_primcaps = 8*8*3
    S_set = [num_capsule, dim_capsule, routings, num_primcaps, m_dim]

    model3 = FSA_net_noS_Capsule(image_size, num_classes, stage_num, lambda_d, S_set)()
    
    print('Loading models ...')

    weight_file1 = '../pre-trained/300W_LP_models/fsanet_capsule_3_16_2_21_5/fsanet_capsule_3_16_2_21_5.h5'
    model1.load_weights(weight_file1)
    print('Finished loading model 1.')
    
    weight_file2 = '../pre-trained/300W_LP_models/fsanet_var_capsule_3_16_2_21_5/fsanet_var_capsule_3_16_2_21_5.h5'
    model2.load_weights(weight_file2)
    print('Finished loading model 2.')

    weight_file3 = '../pre-trained/300W_LP_models/fsanet_noS_capsule_3_16_2_192_5/fsanet_noS_capsule_3_16_2_192_5.h5'
    model3.load_weights(weight_file3)
    print('Finished loading model 3.')

    inputs = Input(shape=(64,64,3))
    x1 = model1(inputs) #1x1
    x2 = model2(inputs) #var
    x3 = model3(inputs) #w/o
    avg_model = Average()([x1,x2,x3])
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=avg_model)
    


    
    print("[INFO] loading face detector...")
    protoPath = os.path.sep.join(["face_detector", "deploy.prototxt"])
    modelPath = os.path.sep.join(["face_detector",
        "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, modelPath)

   
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1024*1)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 768*1)
    


    print('Start detecting pose ...')
    detected_pre = np.empty((1,1,1))

    while True:
        # get video frame
        ret, input_img = cap.read()

        img_idx = img_idx + 1
        img_h, img_w, _ = np.shape(input_img)

        
        if img_idx==1 or img_idx%skip_frame == 0:
            time_detection = 0
            time_network = 0
            time_plot = 0
            
          
            gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(input_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            
            blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(input_img, (300, 300)), 1.0,
                (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
            net.setInput(blob)
            detected = net.forward()

            if detected_pre.shape[2] > 0 and detected.shape[2] == 0:
                detected = detected_pre

            faces = np.empty((detected.shape[2], img_size, img_size, 3))

            input_img = draw_results_ssd(detected,input_img,faces,ad,img_size,img_w,img_h,model,time_detection,time_network,time_plot)
            cv2.imwrite('img/'+str(img_idx)+'.png',input_img)
            
        else:
            input_img = draw_results_ssd(detected,input_img,faces,ad,img_size,img_w,img_h,model,time_detection,time_network,time_plot)


        if detected.shape[2] > detected_pre.shape[2] or img_idx%(skip_frame*3) == 0:
            detected_pre = detected

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':   
    main()
```

The model [code](https://github.com/shamangary/FSA-Net/blob/master/lib/FSANET_model.py) is:

```
import sys
import logging
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Dense, Conv2D,Layer,Reshape,Multiply   
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Activation,Concatenate  
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SeparableConv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

from .capsulelayers import CapsuleLayer
from .capsulelayers import MatMulLayer

from .loupe_keras import NetVLAD

from .utils import register_keras_custom_object

sys.setrecursionlimit(2 ** 20)
np.random.seed(2 ** 10)    


@register_keras_custom_object
class SSRLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, s1, s2, s3, lambda_d, **kwargs):
        super(SSRLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.s1 = s1
        self.s2 = s2
        self.s3 = s3
        self.lambda_d = lambda_d
        self.trainable = False

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs

        a = x[0][:, :, 0] * 0
        b = x[0][:, :, 0] * 0
        c = x[0][:, :, 0] * 0

        s1 = self.s1
        s2 = self.s2
        s3 = self.s3
        lambda_d = self.lambda_d

        di = s1 // 2
        dj = s2 // 2
        dk = s3 // 2

        V = 99

        for i in range(0, s1):
            a = a + (i - di + x[6]) * x[0][:, :, i]
        a = a / (s1 * (1 + lambda_d * x[3]))

        for j in range(0, s2):
            b = b + (j - dj + x[7]) * x[1][:, :, j]
        b = b / (s1 * (1 + lambda_d * x[3])) / (s2 * (1 + lambda_d * x[4]))

        for k in range(0, s3):
            c = c + (k - dk + x[8]) * x[2][:, :, k]
        c = c / (s1 * (1 + lambda_d * x[3])) / (s2 * (1 + lambda_d * x[4])) / (
            s3 * (1 + lambda_d * x[5]))

        pred = (a + b + c) * V

        return pred

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], 3)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            's1': self.s1,
            's2': self.s2,
            's3': self.s3,
            'lambda_d': self.lambda_d
        }
        base_config = super(SSRLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

@register_keras_custom_object
class FeatSliceLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, start_index, end_index,  **kwargs):
        super(FeatSliceLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.start_index = start_index
        self.end_index = end_index
        self.trainable = False

    def call(self, inputs):    
        return inputs[:,self.start_index:self.end_index]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.end_index - self.start_index)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'start_index': self.start_index,
            'end_index': self.end_index
        }
        base_config = super(FeatSliceLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

@register_keras_custom_object
class MomentsLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MomentsLayer,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.trainable = False

    def call(self, inputs):        
        _, var = tf.nn.moments(inputs,axes=-1)
        return var

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[-1])

@register_keras_custom_object
class MatrixMultiplyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MatrixMultiplyLayer,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.trainable = False

    def call(self, inputs):                
        x1, x2 = inputs
    
        return tf.matmul(x1,x2)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shapes):        
        return (input_shapes[0][0],input_shapes[0][1], input_shapes[1][-1])

@register_keras_custom_object
class MatrixNormLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, tile_count,  **kwargs):
        super(MatrixNormLayer,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.trainable = False
        self.tile_count = tile_count

    def call(self, input):                
        sum = K.sum(input,axis=-1,keepdims=True)        
        tiled = K.tile(sum,(1,1,self.tile_count))        
        return tiled

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):        
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1], self.tile_count)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'tile_count': self.tile_count
        }
        base_config = super(MatrixNormLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

@register_keras_custom_object
class PrimCapsLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PrimCapsLayer,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.trainable = False        

    def call(self, inputs):                
        x1, x2, norm = inputs
        return tf.matmul(x1,x2) / norm

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shapes):                
        return input_shapes[-1]

@register_keras_custom_object
class AggregatedFeatureExtractionLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_capsule,  **kwargs):
        super(AggregatedFeatureExtractionLayer,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.trainable = False
        self.num_capsule = num_capsule

    def call(self, input):                
        s1_a = 0
        s1_b = self.num_capsule//3
        feat_s1_div = input[:,s1_a:s1_b,:]
        s2_a = self.num_capsule//3
        s2_b = 2*self.num_capsule//3
        feat_s2_div = input[:,s2_a:s2_b,:]
        s3_a = 2*self.num_capsule//3
        s3_b = self.num_capsule
        feat_s3_div = input[:,s3_a:s3_b,:]

        return [feat_s1_div, feat_s2_div, feat_s3_div]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):        
        last_dim = input_shape[-1]
        partition = self.num_capsule//3
        return [(input_shape[0], partition, last_dim), (input_shape[0], partition, last_dim), (input_shape[0], partition, last_dim)]

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'num_capsule': self.num_capsule
        }
        base_config = super(AggregatedFeatureExtractionLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))


class BaseFSANet(object):
    def __init__(self, image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set):
        self._channel_axis = 3 if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last' else 1

        if self._channel_axis == 1:
            logging.debug("image_dim_ordering = 'th'")            
            self._input_shape = (3, image_size, image_size)
        else:
            logging.debug("image_dim_ordering = 'tf'")
            self._input_shape = (image_size, image_size, 3)           


        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.stage_num = stage_num
        self.lambda_d = lambda_d

        self.num_capsule = S_set[0]
        self.dim_capsule = S_set[1]
        self.routings = S_set[2]

        self.num_primcaps = S_set[3]
        self.m_dim = S_set[4]

        self.F_shape = int(self.num_capsule/3)*self.dim_capsule
        self.map_xy_size = int(8*image_size/64)

        self.is_fc_model = False
        self.is_noS_model = False
        self.is_varS_model = False

    def _convBlock(self, x, num_filters, activation, kernel_size=(3,3)):
        x = SeparableConv2D(num_filters,kernel_size,padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = Activation(activation)(x)
        return x

    def ssr_G_model_build(self, img_inputs):
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
        x = self._convBlock(img_inputs, num_filters=16, activation='relu')
        x_layer1 = AveragePooling2D((2,2))(x)
        x = self._convBlock(x_layer1, num_filters=32, activation='relu')
        x = self._convBlock(x, num_filters=32, activation='relu')        
        x_layer2 = AveragePooling2D((2,2))(x)
        x = self._convBlock(x_layer2, num_filters=64, activation='relu')
        x = self._convBlock(x, num_filters=64, activation='relu')        
        x_layer3 = AveragePooling2D((2,2))(x)
        x = self._convBlock(x_layer3, num_filters=128, activation='relu')
        x_layer4 = self._convBlock(x, num_filters=128, activation='relu')                        
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        s = self._convBlock(img_inputs, num_filters=16, activation='tanh')
        s_layer1 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(s)
        s = self._convBlock(s_layer1, num_filters=32, activation='tanh')
        s = self._convBlock(s, num_filters=32, activation='tanh')        
        s_layer2 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(s)
        s = self._convBlock(s_layer2, num_filters=64, activation='tanh')
        s = self._convBlock(s, num_filters=64, activation='tanh')        
        s_layer3 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(s)
        s = self._convBlock(s_layer3, num_filters=128, activation='tanh')
        s_layer4 = self._convBlock(s, num_filters=128, activation='tanh')                                
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
        s_layer4 = Conv2D(64,(1,1),activation='tanh')(s_layer4)
        x_layer4 = Conv2D(64,(1,1),activation='relu')(x_layer4)

        feat_s1_pre = Multiply()([s_layer4,x_layer4])
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        s_layer3 = Conv2D(64,(1,1),activation='tanh')(s_layer3)
        x_layer3 = Conv2D(64,(1,1),activation='relu')(x_layer3)

        feat_s2_pre = Multiply()([s_layer3,x_layer3])
        
        feat_s3_pre = AveragePooling2D((2,2))(feat_s3_pre) # make sure (8x8x64) feature maps 
    
        return Model(inputs=img_inputs,outputs=[feat_s1_pre,feat_s2_pre,feat_s3_pre], name='ssr_G_model')

    def ssr_F_model_build(self, feat_dim, name_F):
        input_s1_pre = Input((feat_dim,))
        input_s2_pre = Input((feat_dim,))
        input_s3_pre = Input((feat_dim,))

        def _process_input(stage_index, stage_num, num_classes, input_s_pre):            
            feat_delta_s = FeatSliceLayer(0,4)(input_s_pre)            
            delta_s = Dense(num_classes,activation='tanh',name=f'delta_s{stage_index}')(feat_delta_s)            
            
            feat_local_s = FeatSliceLayer(4,8)(input_s_pre)            
            local_s = Dense(units=num_classes, activation='tanh', name=f'local_delta_stage{stage_index}')(feat_local_s)
            
            feat_pred_s = FeatSliceLayer(8,16)(input_s_pre)            
            feat_pred_s = Dense(stage_num*num_classes,activation='relu')(feat_pred_s) 
            pred_s = Reshape((num_classes,stage_num))(feat_pred_s)

            return delta_s, local_s, pred_s

        delta_s1, local_s1, pred_s1 = _process_input(1, self.stage_num[0], self.num_classes, input_s1_pre)
        delta_s2, local_s2, pred_s2 = _process_input(2, self.stage_num[1], self.num_classes, input_s2_pre)
        delta_s3, local_s3, pred_s3 = _process_input(3, self.stage_num[2], self.num_classes, input_s3_pre)        
    
        return Model(inputs=[input_s1_pre,input_s2_pre,input_s3_pre],outputs=[pred_s1,pred_s2,pred_s3,delta_s1,delta_s2,delta_s3,local_s1,local_s2,local_s3], name=name_F)

    def ssr_FC_model_build(self, feat_dim, name_F):
        input_s1_pre = Input((feat_dim,))
        input_s2_pre = Input((feat_dim,))
        input_s3_pre = Input((feat_dim,))

        def _process_input(stage_index, stage_num, num_classes, input_s_pre):
            feat_delta_s = Dense(2*num_classes,activation='tanh')(input_s_pre)
            delta_s = Dense(num_classes,activation='tanh',name=f'delta_s{stage_index}')(feat_delta_s)

            feat_local_s = Dense(2*num_classes,activation='tanh')(input_s_pre)
            local_s = Dense(units=num_classes, activation='tanh', name=f'local_delta_stage{stage_index}')(feat_local_s)

            feat_pred_s = Dense(stage_num*num_classes,activation='relu')(input_s_pre) 
            pred_s = Reshape((num_classes,stage_num))(feat_pred_s)     

            return delta_s, local_s, pred_s   

        delta_s1, local_s1, pred_s1 = _process_input(1, self.stage_num[0], self.num_classes, input_s1_pre)
        delta_s2, local_s2, pred_s2 = _process_input(2, self.stage_num[1], self.num_classes, input_s2_pre)
        delta_s3, local_s3, pred_s3 = _process_input(3, self.stage_num[2], self.num_classes, input_s3_pre)        
           
        return Model(inputs=[input_s1_pre,input_s2_pre,input_s3_pre],outputs=[pred_s1,pred_s2,pred_s3,delta_s1,delta_s2,delta_s3,local_s1,local_s2,local_s3], name=name_F)

    def ssr_feat_S_model_build(self, m_dim):
        input_preS = Input((self.map_xy_size,self.map_xy_size,64))        


        if self.is_varS_model:
            feat_preS = MomentsLayer()(input_preS)
        else:
            feat_preS = Conv2D(1,(1,1),padding='same',activation='sigmoid')(input_preS)        

        feat_preS = Reshape((-1,))(feat_preS)        

        SR_matrix = Dense(m_dim*(self.map_xy_size*self.map_xy_size*3),activation='sigmoid')(feat_preS)
        SR_matrix = Reshape((m_dim,(self.map_xy_size*self.map_xy_size*3)))(SR_matrix)
        
        return Model(inputs=input_preS,outputs=[SR_matrix,feat_preS],name='feat_S_model')

    def ssr_S_model_build(self, num_primcaps, m_dim):
        input_s1_preS = Input((self.map_xy_size,self.map_xy_size,64))
        input_s2_preS = Input((self.map_xy_size,self.map_xy_size,64))
        input_s3_preS = Input((self.map_xy_size,self.map_xy_size,64))

        feat_S_model = self.ssr_feat_S_model_build(m_dim)

        SR_matrix_s1,feat_s1_preS = feat_S_model(input_s1_preS)
        SR_matrix_s2,feat_s2_preS = feat_S_model(input_s2_preS)
        SR_matrix_s3,feat_s3_preS = feat_S_model(input_s3_preS)
        
        feat_pre_concat = Concatenate()([feat_s1_preS,feat_s2_preS,feat_s3_preS])
        SL_matrix = Dense(int(num_primcaps/3)*m_dim,activation='sigmoid')(feat_pre_concat)
        SL_matrix = Reshape((int(num_primcaps/3),m_dim))(SL_matrix)       

        S_matrix_s1 = MatrixMultiplyLayer(name="S_matrix_s1")([SL_matrix,SR_matrix_s1])
        S_matrix_s2 = MatrixMultiplyLayer(name='S_matrix_s2')([SL_matrix,SR_matrix_s2])
        S_matrix_s3 = MatrixMultiplyLayer(name='S_matrix_s3')([SL_matrix,SR_matrix_s3])   ... 

    
....
        
        agg_feat = NetVLAD(feature_size=64, max_samples=self.num_primcaps, cluster_size=self.num_capsule, output_dim=self.num_capsule*self.dim_capsule)(input_primcaps)
        agg_feat = Reshape((self.num_capsule,self.dim_capsule))(agg_feat)

        feat_s1_div, feat_s2_div, feat_s3_div = AggregatedFeatureExtractionLayer(num_capsule=self.num_capsule)(agg_feat)        

        feat_s1_div = Reshape((-1,))(feat_s1_div)
        feat_s2_div = Reshape((-1,))(feat_s2_div)
        feat_s3_div = Reshape((-1,))(feat_s3_div)
        
        return Model(inputs=input_primcaps,outputs=[feat_s1_div,feat_s2_div,feat_s3_div], name='ssr_Agg_model')                

class FSA_net_NetVLAD(BaseNetVLADFSANet):
    def __init__(self, image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set):
        super(FSA_net_NetVLAD, self).__init__(image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set)
        self.is_varS_model = False    
    
class FSA_net_Var_NetVLAD(BaseNetVLADFSANet):
    def __init__(self, image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set):
        super(FSA_net_Var_NetVLAD,  





class BaseMetricFSANet(BaseFSANet):
    def __init__(self, image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set):
        super(BaseMetricFSANet, self).__init__(image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set) 
        
    def ssr_aggregation_model_build(self, shape_primcaps):
        input_primcaps = Input(shape_primcaps)

        metric_feat = MatMulLayer(16,type=1)(input_primcaps)
        metric_feat = MatMulLayer(3,type=2)(metric_feat)

        feat_s1_div, feat_s2_div, feat_s3_div = AggregatedFeatureExtractionLayer(num_capsule=self.num_capsule)(metric_feat)        

        feat_s1_div = Reshape((-1,))(feat_s1_div)
        feat_s2_div = Reshape((-1,))(feat_s2_div)
        feat_s3_div = Reshape((-1,))(feat_s3_div)
        
        return Model(inputs=input_primcaps,outputs=[feat_s1_div,feat_s2_div,feat_s3_div], name='ssr_Metric_model')     
    
class FSA_net_Metric(BaseMetricFSANet):
    def __init__(self, image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set):
        super(FSA_net_Metric, self).__init__(image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set)
        self.is_varS_model = False    

class FSA_net_Var_Metric(BaseMetricFSANet):
    def __init__(self, image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set):
        super(FSA_net_Var_Metric, self).__init__(image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set)
        self.is_varS_model = True
        
class FSA_net_noS_Metric(BaseMetricFSANet):
    def __init__(self, image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set):
        super(FSA_net_noS_Metric, self).__init__(image_size,num_classes,stage_num,lambda_d, S_set)
        self.is_noS_model = True
```

This is the error I'm getting. How to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/redhwan/2/HPE/FSA-Net/demo/demo_FSANET_ssd.py", line 219, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/redhwan/2/HPE/FSA-Net/demo/demo_FSANET_ssd.py", line 126, in main
    model1 = FSA_net_Capsule(image_size, num_classes, stage_num, lambda_d, S_set)()
  File "/home/redhwan/2/HPE/FSA-Net/demo/../lib/FSANET_model.py", line 431, in __call__
    ssr_S_model = self.ssr_S_model_build(num_primcaps=self.num_primcaps,m_dim=self.m_dim)           
  File "/home/redhwan/2/HPE/FSA-Net/demo/../lib/FSANET_model.py", line 370, in ssr_S_model_build
    feat_S_model = self.ssr_feat_S_model_build(m_dim)
  File "/home/redhwan/2/HPE/FSA-Net/demo/../lib/FSANET_model.py", line 360, in ssr_feat_S_model_build
    SR_matrix = Dense(m_dim*(self.map_xy_size*self.map_xy_size*3),activation='sigmoid')(feat_preS)
  File "/home/redhwan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 897, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/home/redhwan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2416, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
  File "/home/redhwan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py", line 1154, in build
    raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

Please let me know what's the reason behind the error and how to fix it.

Also, the error when trying to train is:

**ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to Dense should be defined. Found None**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating `tensorflow ==2.2`.0 to `tensorflow ==2.3`.